# Version specific synonym suggestion: [spacy-3] to [spacy]

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request

I'd like to suggest that [spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spacy) and [spacy-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spacy-3) on Stack Overflow be considered tag synonyms, with [spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spacy) as the canonical form. I am unable to propose this directly because I am not a moderator. Based on [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) posts I assume this is the appropriate way to make a request.

I am one of the spaCy developers and we monitor the [spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spacy) tag to help users. We could also monitor the [spacy-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spacy-3) tag, but based on the questions so far it doesn't seem to be used significantly differently from the [spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spacy) tag, so it doesn't seem to have any useful information.

Comment: [tag:Spacy-3] only have 45 questions. A manual retag could be a faster alternative.

Comment: spacy-3 is a relatively recent release, so I'm concerned people would continue to use the tag in the future, when it will be even less relevant as users of older versions decline.

Comment: Please don't do any manual retagging, as it is a very disruptive procedure for everyone involved.

Comment: Just an update on this, but since I posted this the tags are frequently used together, and the spacy-3 tag is basically used at random. Would really appreciate it if these could be made synonyms.